Workaround for out of memory: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]
I'm trying to generate a PDF in R with this code
  tools::texi2pdf("Genesmsa.tex", clean=TRUE, quiet = TRUE,
       texi2dvi = getOption("texi2dvi"),
       texinputs=system.file("tex", package="msa"), index = TRUE)

where Genesmsa.tex is automatically written through this
msaPrettyPrint(Genesmsa, output="tex", showNames="left",
             showLogo="top", askForOverwrite=FALSE, verbose=TRUE)

and it is made like this
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{texshade}

\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
\hoffset=0pt
\voffset=0pt
\paperwidth=11in
\paperheight=8.5in
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\relax
\else
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\fi
\oddsidemargin=-0.9in
\topmargin=-0.7in
\textwidth=10.8in
\textheight=7.9in

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{texshade}{path/input_sequence.fasta}
\seqtype{P}
\shadingmode{identical}
\threshold{50}
\showconsensus[ColdHot]{bottom}
\shadingcolors{blues}
\showsequencelogo[chemical]{top}
\hidelogoscale
\shownames{left}
\nameseq{1}{NC 000019.10:22634324-22667671 ZNF492  organism Homo sapiens   GeneID 57615   chromosome 19 }
\nameseq{2}{NC 072418.2:c24826387-24794847 LOC739694  organism Pan troglodytes   GeneID 739694   chromosome 20 }
\nameseq{3}{NC 000079.7:c67903321-67892583 Zfp85  organism Mus musculus   GeneID 22746   chromosome 13 }
\shownumbering{right}
\showlegend
\end{texshade}
\end{document}

calling this input_sequence.fasta. I think this file is too big (1400 lines in FASTA format, for 112 kb) but when I try to run the code in R or compile the .tex file through TexStudio, I see this error
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.
cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
)) (C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpoFrvnT/seq279c535925e3.fasta:
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\seq@line ->
            TGACTTCAAGCAGTGTTTTCACAGTGTTGTCATAAAGATCTTTCACCTCCCTGGTTAGCTGTAT...
l.39 \end{texshade}
                   
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7918 strings out of 474423
 96311 string characters out of 5741246
 1945496 words of memory out of 5000000
 30294 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558710 words of font info for 39 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 10000i,1n,65p,203b,10447s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Googling around I saw I can enlarge the allocated memory for miktex. I tried to modify the file texmfapp.ini in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\config where it is installed but it's not working.
Any solution?
Edit: This is an example of what is insite the .fasta generated through msaPrettyPrint
>NC_000019.10:22634324-22667671 ZNF492 [organism=Homo sapiens] [GeneID=57615] [chromosome=19]
--------------------------------------------------GTCTTTGTCTCTCGCTGCAGTCG--GAGTA
TGGTCTAGTGTTCGCTGTTCTGCGTCCTCTGGTCCTAGAGGCCCATCCTCTGTGGCCCTGTGACCTGCAGGTATTGGGAG
ATCCACAGCTAAGACGCTAGGACCCCCTGGAAGCCTAGAAACGGTGAGAGTGCCGGGTCCGACATCCCGAGAGAGGGGAA
>NC_072418.2:c24826387-24794847 LOC739694 [organism=Pan troglodytes] [GeneID=739694] [chromosome=20]
AATCAGGCACGCGGTTGGAGCGGAAAGGGCGGCTTCCGGGATGTGGCGGGGTCTTTGTCTCTCGCTGCAGCCGGAGTTCC
TGGTCTCGTCTTCGCGCTTCTGTGTCCTCTGCTCGTAGAGGCCCAGCCTCTGTGGTCCTGTCACCTGCAGGTATTGG-GA
ATCCACAGCTAAGATGCCAGGACCCCTTGGAAGCCTAGAAGTGGTGAGAGTGCCGGGTCCGACATCCCTAGAGAGGAGAA
GGGGCTGGTTGGAACCGGTGGCAAGAGGCTGTGGCGGGACTCAGGCCTCCCCGCAGTCAGCTCCACAATCCGTGCCCCGA
GTTCTCCTTGCCCAGCTCGGCCTCAGTCCCCTTCAGCGATAAGATGG-CGGCTGCGCTGACAGCCAGGCTCCGGG-CGTC
CTGTCTCTTCCCTGCCCAGTGACTGTGCCCTGAGCTGGAGCCCTCTCCGGGCAGCTCTACACGCGCAGCGCCGCGTCTCT
>NC_000079.7:c67903321-67892583 Zfp85 [organism=Mus musculus] [GeneID=22746] [chromosome=13]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compiling the code with this file, in my case, works fine. With more lines, it does not.
Edit2: changing values inside texmfapp.ini with large numbers, gives errors found in pdflatex.log
2024-07-21 19:38:58,222+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Bad parameter value.
2024-07-21 19:38:58,222+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: maxValue="30000", minValue="200", parameterName="stack_size", value="1000000000"
2024-07-21 19:38:58,222+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex\TeXAndFriends\TeXMFMemoryHandlerImpl.h:242
2024-07-21 19:38:58,222+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Bad parameter value.
2024-07-21 19:38:58,223+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: maxValue="30000", minValue="200", parameterName="stack_size", value="1000000000"
2024-07-21 19:38:58,223+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex\TeXAndFriends\TeXMFMemoryHandlerImpl.h
2024-07-21 19:38:58,223+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 242


Even for  people expert in R and genetics will be hard provide any useful answer if nobody can reproduce your issue  to test the solutions. You should show a minimal working example with the DNA sequences o the complete R script able to produce "as is" that output.  Of course, I am not asking you to publish here your work,  but  an example minimal but  reproducible example with public sequences or dummy fake sequences.

I think any sequence with 1400 lines should do the work. I tried editing the .fasta deleting most of the rows and it works fine. I think it's machine dependent, I have 8 GB RAM. If your's is larger, maybe you need much lines in the .fasta. In any case, I added an example of how my sequence is (3 species). With this lines it compliles correctly (so no problem with the code, but with the hardware)

which limit did you increase (needs to be the input stack size,not the main memory)

hmm actually with texlive latex I trued 900 lines and exceeded main mem not input stack

dvilualtex helps with main mem, but still hits same input stack size

if using latex the physical memory of your machine does not matter as tex does not do dynamic allocation what matters is the miktex equivalent of the texlive setting stack_size = 10000      % simultaneous input sources

I tried changing the limit in the file I wrote in the post but maybe is not the correct one (I'm on Windows if that's help, and MikTeX 4.12)

the config on texlive is a bit different but you should probably show exactly what changes you made in that file, you should be able to increase the input stack I would have expected, add it to your question and a miktex user will comment

looks like it is also called stack_size in miktex https://docs.miktex.org/manual/texmfdefaults.html

Tried increasing all values (not only stack_size), gives me errors in pdflatex.
Add part of the log in the discussion

You should report this directly to the texshade author.
